# Maya RuntimeError: OpenMaya.py (kInvalidParameter): Index not in valid Range

Tags: python, runtime-error, maya

I am writing a python tool that will store attributes of the stereoscopic camera in a scene into a JSON file.

I use this code to get the selected plane with the attributes I need to store

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om

selected = om.MSelectionList()
om.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(selected)
obj = om.MObject()
selected.getDependNode(0,obj)
sel = om.MFnDependencyNode(obj).name()
if sel != "npl_Near_ZP":
    cmds.confirmDialog(title= 'Error:', message = 'Error: Please Select the correct plane', button =['OK'])
else:
    jsonCreate(sel)
```

It was working perfectly before but now when I try to the script, I get the following runtime error and I 've sort of hit a wall here cause I don't understand what the problem is

> Error: RuntimeError: file S:\Maya_2018_DI\build\Release\runTime\Python\Lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMaya.py line 18296: (kInvalidParameter): Index not in valid range #

I m still new to Maya so any help will be greatly appreciated

> update I restarted my computer and the script is now running as it should. Can anyone explain this behaviour in case it happens again

Comment: Is it possible that there is a name conflict ?

Comment: @DrWeeny That could be it, I'll check everything again, I just don't understand why it would work for a whole day only to stop now

Comment: @DrWeeny I restarted my computer and now the script is working again, I didn't change anything in the names either